# which of the following statements about a group are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1.If a group has an odd number of elements then there exists no element which is inverse of itself.
2.If a group contains even no of elements then there exists only one element which is inverse of itself.

I am confused that if I have odd no of elements then in that case  I will have one identity element and then I will be left with even no of elements,which can be  paired up so then I will be left with atleast one element which is inverse of itself so then in the case where the group has even no of elements then can't we argue in the similar fashion .

Answer (score 1):

"If a group contains even no of elements then there exists only one element which is inverse of itself."

What groups on four elements do yo know?

Comment: {1,-1,i,-i} with operation of multiplication but here inverse of i is -i and inverse of -1 is -1 itself so thats what I said that there exists only one element which is the inverse of itself .

Comment: @Radha: There also exists another group on four elements; have a look at that one.

Comment: Sir then in general there may be many groups on 4 elements , I am not getting about which group are you talking about ?

Comment: @Radha: There are only two non-isomorphic groups on four elements.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are false. The elements that are *not* their own inverses can be partitioned into (unordered) pairs of the form $\{a,a^{-1}\}$, hence the number of elements that are not selfinverse is even. Thus in an odd group there is at least one selfinverse element (indeed, the neutral element has this property); and in an even group, the number of such elements is even and - as the neutral element has this property - is at least $2$.

Comment: Sorry but couldn't get your last statement  "the number of such elements is even adn - as the neutral element has this property - is at least 22."

Comment: @RADHAGOGIA If you remove elements from $G$ always in form of pairs $\{a,a^{-1}\}$ then you never change the parity of the set; so if you start with en even set $G$, you must finally end with an even set. This *could* be the empty set, but in fact it can't - because the neutral elements is among the remaining elements